# Trying to get to the next level within a json array in php

Tags: php, json

I am using PHP to extract data from the limelight CRM. I am hitting the prospect_find API call that allows me to return a list of prospect ids as well as a JSON encoded prospect_view object of each prospect. I can seperate the prospect id, but i am having trouble getting down to the next level of date to extract the actual prospect data that i need

This my code that call the API

```
    $find_prospects = array(
    'username' => $LLAPI_USER,
    'password' => $LLAPI_PASS,
    'method' => 'prospect_find',
    'campaign_id' => '272',
    'start_date' => $startDate,
    'start_time' => '00:00:00',
    'end_date' => $endDate,
    'end_time' => '23:59:59',
    'return_type' => 'prospect_view'
);
$ch = curl_init($limelight_crm_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($find_prospects));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $retOrder = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
parse_str($retOrder);
echo $retOrder;
if ($retOrder === false) {
    echo "No prospects to extract";
} else {
    //var_dump ($data);
    $prospectData = json_decode($data[0]);
    echo $prospectData;
    $counter = 0;
    $all_prospect_counter = 0;
    $prospectids = Array();
    $total_prospect = count(explode(',', $prospect_ids));
    foreach (explode(',', $prospect_ids) AS $prospectid) {
    $prospectData = json_decode($data);
//      print_r ($prospectData);
    echo $prospectData[$prospectid]->$response_code;

//      $arr = explode(',', $prospect_ids);
//      print($arr[$counter]->{"response_code"});

    $counter++;
}
```

the truncated response is here:

```
response_code=100&total_prospects=1182&prospect_ids=3658707,&data=
{"3658707":
    {"response_code":"100",
    "campaign_id":"272",
    "first_name":"XXXX",
    "last_name":"XXXX",
    "address":"XX",
    "address2":"",
    "city":"XXXX",
    state":"XX",
    "state_id":"XX",
    "zip":"XXXXX",
    "country":"XX",
    "phone":"XXXX",
    "email":"XXXXXX",
    "ip_address":"XXXXXX",
    "date_created":"2017-02-12+00%3A04%3A07",
    "affiliate":"XX",
    "sub_affiliate":"XXXX"
}
```

If someone could help point me the right direction i would appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: I have resolved my problem: the functioning code is listed below
My first problem was that I was not setting my json decode to an array, so i was getting the not a object error. My second issue was that I was not looping over the proper array values. And lastly, i was not able to keep the actual identifer inside my array. As i have learned, the id value needs to stay in it original array and then i can import it using a counter.

Comment: $prospectData = json_decode($data, true);
    $counter = 0;
    $total_prospect = count(explode(',', $prospect_ids));
    $arr = explode(',', $prospect_ids);
    foreach($prospectData as $prospect){
    $first_name  = $prospect['first_name'];
    $last_name  = $prospect['last_name'];
    $address   = $prospect['address'];
    $city   = $prospect['city'];
    $state   = $prospect['state'];
    $zip   = $prospect['zip'];
    $email    = $prospect['email'];
    $date_created = $prospect['date_created'];
    $campaign_id  = $prospect['campaign_id'];
// sql statement here

Answer (score 0):

```
        $prospectData = json_decode($data, true);
        $counter = 0;
        $all_prospect_counter = 0;
        $prospectids = Array();
        $total_prospect = count(explode(',', $prospect_ids));
        $arr = explode(',', $prospect_ids);
        foreach($prospectData as $prospect){
            $first_name     = $prospect['first_name'];
            $last_name      = $prospect['last_name'];
            $address        = $prospect['address'];
            $city           = $prospect['city'];
            $state          = $prospect['state'];
            $zip            = $prospect['zip'];
            $email          = $prospect['email'];
            $date_created   = $prospect['date_created'];
            $campaign_id    = $prospect['campaign_id'];


            $query_pop_temp = "INSERT INTO `hydra`.`Prospects` (`ProspectID`,`FirstName`,`LastName`,`StreetAddress`, `City`,`State`, `zip`,`Emailaddress`,`Created`,`Campaign`, `ListID`)
                VALUES ($arr[$counter], '$first_name', '$last_name', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$zip', '$email', '$date_created', $campaign_id, 'CxBkt4')";
            $result_pop_temp = $mysqli->query($query_pop_temp);  
        $counter++;
        }
```